# freeform:entries to display "File Upload" field

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, file-uploads

I'm using this basic code to output form results:

```
{exp:freeform:entries form_name="{segment_3}"}
 {freeform:all_form_fields}
  <p>
   <label>{freeform:field_label}:</label>
   {freeform:field_output}
  </p>
 {/freeform:all_form_fields}
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

It works great for all of my forms, except for when I encounter a File Upload field: it just outputs the filename (without a link to the file). Is there a better way write this code for possible File fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

When looping through your {freeform:all_form_fields} you will need to test the {freeform:field_output} and alter the html markup you dump your field data into.

IE:

```
{exp:freeform:entries form_name="{segment_3}"}
    {freeform:all_form_fields}
    <p>
        <label>{freeform:field_label}</label>
        {if freeform:field_type == 'text'}
            {freeform:field_output}
        {/if}
        {if freeform:field_type == 'file'}
            <img src="{freeform:field_output}">
        {/if}
    </p>
    {/freeform:all_form_fields}
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

Not sure if the field_type is actually named file for a file upload you will need to find out.

Here is the documentation area of freeform i pulled this syntax from.

http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/entries/#variable_pairs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, mattidjohn. I just had to change field_type to "file_upload" and manually type in the URL to the file, since field_output only produces a filename. Since you can choose Upload Destination per File Upload field, I don't exactly like hard-coding it to one upload location, but I don't see any variable to reference to find the Upload Destination. (If so, that would make the code scalable and better.)

```
{if freeform:field_type == 'file_upload'}
  <a href="{site_url}docs/{freeform:field_output}">{freeform:field_output}</a>
{/if}
```